# Python- Multiple os.path.split()

Tags: python, os.path

Do you guys know a more intelligent way to do this ?

```
os.path.split(os.path.split(os.path.split(os.getcwd())[0])[0])[0]
```

`os.getcwd()` is for example:

```
/my/path/to/my/directory
```

I should get

```
/my/path/
```

That is really an exaggeration and duplication of the `os.path.split()`

Thanks

Comment: Why not try a regex after calling `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: Have you heard of [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)?

Comment: @user2357112 Surely he has, as it's mentioned in the documentation of the function he's using...

Comment: @user2357112 better but still repetitive if I have to 3 of them ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest you using `os.sep`:

`os.sep.join(os.getcwd().split(os.sep)[:-3])`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`pathlib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib/)

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path('/my/path/to/my/directory').parents[2]
print(path)

>>> /my/path
```

As of Python 3.4, `pathlib` is part of the standard libraries, but you can install in earlier versions

> pip install pathlib

Comment: Works well but you have to download pathlib. 
It is already in your site-packages ?

Comment: @MathieuChâteauvert I just updated my answer with that information